# the offset of the highest value of one vector data for the last value

Tags: matlab

how to get the shift of the highest value of the data compared to the last value of the vector

```
V = [2 5 7 1 99 99 5 22]
```

for this example the result is : `8 - 6 = 2` ; `8 = size(V)`

`max(V) = 99`, but `V(5)=99` and `V(6)=99` .

`max(5,6)=6` and `8 - 6 = 2`

I can reformulate my problem like this: how to find the index of the maximum values of one vector and if there is the same greatest value several times, I want to find the greatest of the indices

Comment: It's totally unclear how you got `8 - 3` from `V`, or what either one of them have to do with the highest value of the data (`99`?) or the last value of the vector (`6`?)...

Comment: @excaza : it's just an example. I have a vector of 2000 values and I look for each value its offset from the highest on the last 8 values

Comment: It still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @excaza: that's my problem, I do not have a choice !!!

Comment: @excaza: how to find the index of the maximum values of one vector and if there is the same greatest value several times, I want to find the greatest of the indices

Comment: @excaza : sorry 8 - 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the maximum value:

```
V = rand(1,10); 
[~,max_idx] = max(V);
```

If there are several identical "maximum values" in `V`, this will give you the first. So for your case, you'll just need to reverse the vector `V` to get the last (the largest index).

```
[~,max_idx] = max(fliplr(V));
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the last index of the maximum value:

```
ind = numel(V) - find(V == max(V), 1, 'last')
```